# Is it possible to process a for loop in parallel within the same stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, loops, stored-procedures, foreach, parallel-processing

Have a SQL Server stored procedure where I want to loop through a set of options that I read from a table.  So say a table has 100 options.  My stored procedure will loop through these options and for each option I need to do some checks - by querying few specific tables based on the option and flag a status related to it.

Is it possible for me to split the for loop such that row 1 -50 are processed in one loop and row 51-100 in another loop and I am able to run both of these in parallel?.  I see a way where you can run multiple stored procedure in parallel through a SQL job or other means but not able to see if I can get a for loop to execute in parallel by splitting it.

Comment: Instead of doing all this looping how about if we help you find a set based solution? Then you don't need loops at all. But no, you can't do multi-threading in a stored procedure, at least not in t-sql.

Comment: Thanks Sean.  Will look into logic to see if Set based logic can be put in place given multi-threading is not feasible

Answer (score 0):

Treating your question as academic, and not considering whether a set-based solution might exist, since there isn't nearly enough information to do that.

No you can't do this in a single loop (or in two separate loops for that matter) using standard TSQL, because TSQL is synchronous.  Even if you "split" the loop, the second procedure call could not start until the first call finished.  They would not run in parallel.

To run two loops in parallel, you would have to introduce some other language.   The results of [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql%20server%20asynchronous%20stored%20procedure&oq=sql%20server%20asynchronous%20stored%20procedure&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.9383j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) turned up quite a few ideas but the first few I looked at had lots of warnings of pitfalls and unexpected results.  Up to you if you want to experiment with any of them.

Comment: Thanks Tab. Yes we were considering shifting this logic to another language however wanted to see if we can do it in a stored procedure.  As I commented above will have to re-visit the logic to see if it can be done with a set based logic.